# Journalctl says: "Failed to search journal ACL: Operation not supported"

Tags: zfs, systemd-journald

When I run `journalctl -xe` as a non-root user, I get the following error:

```
bgeron@machine:~$ journalctl -xe
Failed to search journal ACL: Operation not supported
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be caused by mounting ZFS with the wrong options. Journald [requires access control lists](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html), which are off by default in ZFS on Linux.

To enable access control lists, you must set the `acltype=posixacl` property on your filesystems. According to the zfs(8) man page, it is also recommended to set the `xattr=sa` property, which is more efficient, but only supported by "relatively new" ZFS implementations.

Set the properties as follows, for each filesystem:

```
zfs set acltype=posixacl poolname/path/to/fs && zfs set xattr=sa poolname/path/to/fs
```

After setting these properties, restart journald:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

See also: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/16954